# Loading Modules when the ModuleLoader is a Dependency

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm currently working on a minecraft plugin that needs to load different Modules. However, the plugin that loads the modules is also a dependency for each Module. Because of this, when I try to load a module, it throws a NoClassDefFoundError. How can I use the module loader as a dependency for the module aswell?

Code for module loader:

```java
  private void loadModules() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        if(SaturnPrisons.getInstance().getDataFolder() == null || !SaturnPrisons.getInstance().getDataFolder().exists()){
            return;
        }

        File dir = new File(SaturnPrisons.getInstance().getDataFolder() + File.separator + "modules");

        if(!dir.exists()){
            dir.mkdir();
            return;
        }

        if(dir.listFiles() == null){
            return;
        }

        for(File file: dir.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            }

            String[] arrayOfFile = file.getName().split("\\.");


            if (!arrayOfFile[arrayOfFile.length - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("jar")) {
                continue;
            }

            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(file);

            JarEntry jarEntry = jarFile.getJarEntry("module.yml");

            if (jarEntry == null) {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " could not load! module.yml missing!");
                continue;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = jarFile.getInputStream(jarEntry);

            Map<String, Map<String, String>> values = new Yaml().load(inputStream);

            if (!values.containsKey("main")) {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " could not load! Main Class not in module.yml!");
                continue;
            }

            String main = "" + values.get("main");

            URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{file.toURI().toURL()});

            Class<?> jarClass = loader.loadClass(main);

            Object instance = jarClass.newInstance();

            if (!(instance instanceof SaturnModule)) {
                System.out.println(file.getName() + " could not load! Main Class was not a SaturnModule class!");
                continue;
            }

            SaturnModule saturnModule = (SaturnModule) instance;

            saturnModule.load(SaturnPrisons.getInstance());

            System.out.println("Module Loaded: " + file.getName());

        }
```

Error

````
[00:15:16 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling SaturnPrisons v3.00-SNAPSHOT (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/saturnplugins/saturnprisons/modules/SaturnModule
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at com.saturnplugins.saturnprisons.modules.ModuleManager.loadModules(ModuleManager.java:77) ~[?:?]
        at com.saturnplugins.saturnprisons.modules.ModuleManager.<init>(ModuleManager.java:21) ~[?:?]
        at com.saturnplugins.saturnprisons.SaturnPrisons.onEnable(SaturnPrisons.java:16) ~[?:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:403) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:381) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:330) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:422) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.l(MinecraftServer.java:383) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:338) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer.init(DedicatedServer.java:272) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:545) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-dcd1643-e60fc34]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_291]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.saturnplugins.saturnprisons.modules.SaturnModule
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
        ... 25 more```
````

Comment: Can you share part of the stacktrace to see where this occurs?

Comment: I have updated it with the error @KevinHooke , The error is happening on the line "Class<?> jarClass = loader.loadClass(main);"